# Gnome Desktop Icons Alignment

Tags: desktop, icons, alignment, gnome

It has been a long time since I started to compare the gnome desktop to the windows desktop. 
But since I began to use linux, I realized that the "gnome way" to align the icons on Desktop is not that nice for me. And comparing to Windows's way, windows is better for me. (remember, for me).
I'd like to know if anyone has some tip to make "gnome desktop icon alignment" more like windows do. I tried to reduce the icon's size, did something, but was not that all. 
So, could anyone tell another tip? I like when I put something on windows desktop, and wherever I put the file, Windows organize the file and put the icon right after the last icon (in a cascade style) (and automatically).
Any tips?

Comment: Unless you're looking for a programming solution this question will probably be moved to Superuser.

Comment: @Alexandre: What do you mean with "Superuser"?

Comment: http://superuser.com is a site of the *Stackoverflow Trilogy* geared toward computer usage questions. Stackoverflow is about programming and not all questions are appropriate here. Moderators can move questions between the trilogy sites as needed.

Comment: I checked super user. A excellent site too. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Follow my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1246321/1034662) in askubuntu 100% work

Answer (score 1):

### A different Linux desktop manager

The latest version of Gnome (**Gnome 3**) will snap desktop icons Windows-style by default (once you configure it to *show* the icons), and others have said **KDE** can do likewise.

### If you must still use Gnome 2:

Apparently a couple people have come up with a tiled background to give the illusion of alignment; if such a thing is of interest to you, check here (and then set your desktop background to whatever you previously had when you are finished):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?s=34f1c9161626ba4cdafd8652b0ef0caf&t=1679875

Answer (score 1):

Gnome 3.22

Open dconf editor. 
1. Navigate to 
-  org.gnome.nautilus.desktop > text-ellipsis-limit  1
- org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view > text-ellipsis-limit  ['0']
- org.gnome.SessionManager > auto-save-session  true

2.-Restart

3. On desktop right click and

   - check Keep aligned then Organise Desktop by name or
   - uncheck Keep aligNed and Organise Desktop by name.

This is the most you can get comparing to Windows's way (Gnome Desktop is really an unprofessional real mess!)

P.S. On org.gnome.nautilus.desktop > font xx --try different values to enlarge/shorten the icon label.